# How can I enable Touch events on Chromium when running in kiosk mode?

Tags: ubuntu, kde, chrome

I'm having an issue wherein touch events do not work on a touch-capable monitor when Chromium is started with the `--kiosk` flag. If I remove the flag, touch events behave as I'd like them to.

Here's the command I'm using to start Chromium:

```
 chromium-browser --kiosk \                                                                                                                                              
                  --incognito \                                                                                                                                          
                  --enable-logging \                                                                                                                                     
                  --v=1 \                                                                                                                                                
                  --force-device-scale-factor=1.0 \                                                                                                                      
                  --disable-session-crashed-bubble \                                                                                                                     
                   --disable-pinch \                                                                                                                                      
                   --remote-debugging-port=9922 \                                                                                                                         
                   http://localhost:8080 > /home/$USER/Documents/kiosk.log 2>&1 &
```

I've also tried providing the `--touch-devices` flag, which has no effect.

So, am I missing a flag (or similar)? Is this a bug?

Environment: Chromium 71.0.3559.6 Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Did you find a solution @pdoherty926?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `--enabled --touch-events`?

Also, I don't know about your set up, but I've read about [someone](http://www.lukebrowning.com/hardware/raspberry-pi/touch-screen-chromium-kiosk-on-the-raspberry-pi/) who installed `x11-xserver-utils unclutter` from APT as well.

Hope this is helpful

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36762764/5352605)

Comment: Thanks, but adding these two flags to the above has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I think the flag should be

`--touch-events=enabled`